# How to set increment progress and have a progress bar update on a button press?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I can't seem to get my progress bar to update when the button is pressed. Here is how I have the code written.

```
    mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            double startingBudget = Double.parseDouble(mStartingBudgetInput.getText().toString());
            mProgressBar.setMax((int)(startingBudget * 100));

            double amountSpent = Double.parseDouble(mAmountSpentInput.getText().toString());
            mProgressBar.incrementProgressBy(((int)(amountSpent * 100)) / ((int)(startingBudget * 100)));

            Log.d("subButton", "onClick: " + startingBudget * 100);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your button is clicked, you can call `ProgressBar`'s `setMax()` and then `setProgress()` methods to show the progress.

Check if your progress bar XML is something like this

```
<ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/pb_products"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="6dp"/>
```

And call a method like this to update your progress in the progress bar

```
private void setProgressBar(ProgressBar progressBar, int progress, int max) {
    progressBar.setMax(max);
    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
    progressBar.animate();
}
```